# Should i select and use another partition or Extend root ? (CentOS)

Tags: centos, centos7, partition

I want to switch my current working partition to an existent one on the disk under CentOS.
How to achieve this ?

PS : i want to switch to the larger partition (/dev/sdc or /dev/sdb/cl-home) (currently i am using KVM and others on `/dev/sdb3/cl-root`) so that i can install KVM and many VMs, is it possible ?
Btw `parted`  says `/dev/sda` is selected while i'm on `/dev/sdb/cl-root`

Or maybe to achieve that, should i mount the `/dev/sdb3/cl-home` at the "`/`" mountpoint ?
EDIT : should i try to create a partition after selecting `/dev/sdc` (or `/dev/sdb/sdb3/cl-home`) disk with  gparted like so :

```
(parted) select /dev/sdc
```

Please see attached partitions on my disk.
[image: e]
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It is not accessible to some readers. Post the text instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe to achieve that, should i mount the /dev/sdb3/cl-home at the
> "/" mountpoint ?

No, that will make the system unusable. OS and mount points are installed at `/` ("rootfs").  Just because the system has certain volumes allocated doesn't mean you have to use them, as sysadmin you can rearrange storage.

You already have Linux LVM, which has useful features. Use logical volumes, not partitions.

Get the status of PVs, VGs, and LVs: `pvs; vgs; lvs;`

From the `lsblk` output we can infer that VG `cl` spans `sdb3` and `sdc1`. Not ideal: requires both disks to be online for the VG to function, and performance will be uneven across the PVs as one also stores `/`.

Check how much space `/home` is actually using with `df -h /home`. It might be much less than its 380G size, given the installer's habit of giving the remainder to `/home`.

First of all, make a backup and test restoring it.

Regarding storing your VM guest data, create new LVs on new VGs. This separates the data from the OS install, allowing the disks to be moved independently.

```
# Get unique IDs for your disks, and determine which are in use.  
# Unique IDs prevent problems if the device letter (/dev/sdd for example) changed.
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/wwn*
# Create a new data VG on empty disks. Your disk names will be different.  
# Note the use of the entire disk, partitions are not necessary
vgcreate data /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x60022480bd6bef1caf06ed2a65b007c4
# Create a LV
lvcreate --name vm --size 100g data
# Create a file system. 
mkfs.xfs -L vm /dev/data/vm
# Edit /etc/fstab to mount /dev/data/vm  on  /srv
# Your mount point probably will be different
```

Optionally, determine how you might safely remove `/dev/sdc1` from `cl`. Some file systems cannot be reduced, this may require a backup, reduce the LV, and restore. And finally, `pvmove` and `vgreduce`.